# What are KeePassXC Encryption Settings?

Tags: encryption, password-management

I'd like to know what is an extremely secure configuration with the given options for KeePassXC database:

- Encryption Algorithm: AES 256, Twofish 256, ChaCha20 256
- Key Derivation Function: Argon2, AES-KDF
- Transform Rounds: 25 (benchmark 1 sec delay)
- Memory usage: 64Mb
- Parallelism: 4 threads

In particular, I would like to understand better how transform rounds/memory usage and parallelism settings influence the level of security and what would be recommended for an extremely sensitive database.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"how transform rounds/memory usage and parallelism settings influence the level of security"* Against what? What's your threat model? Please [Edit] your question; without knowing what you are trying to protect against, we can't know what measures may be appropriate or sufficient.